# Element with xpath not found codeception

Tags: php, xpath, laravel, codeception

I am using CodeCeption to test a website for work. I've never used CodeCeption and I'm just trying to get my first test to work. I just want to login, but my login box is using jQuery UI (which means the login button doesn't have an ID). The website is https://moveyourmountain.org

I used this in the Chome Console:

`$x('//button/span[text()="Login"]')`

and got this response:

`[<span class=​"ui-button-text">​Login​</span>​]`

so my xpath is right, and selects the right thing. However, in CodeCeption I have this:

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Login as a regular user.');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->click('LOGIN');
$I->fillField('email', 'some@one.com');
$I->fillField('password', 'test123');
$I->click(['xpath' => '//button/span[text()="Login"]']);
$I->see('MY ACCOUNT');
```

and every time I run it I get this in my terminal:

```
Sorry, I couldn't click {"xpath":"//button/span[text()="Login"]"}:
Element with xpath '//button/span[text()="Login"]' was not found on page.

Scenario Steps:
5. I click {"xpath":"//button/span[text()="Login"]"}
4. I fill field "password","test123"
3. I fill field "email","some@one.com"
2. I click "LOGIN"
1. I am on page "/"
```

I am using PhpBrowser if that makes a difference. Any help is appreciated. I have no idea how to go about testing this because it obviously isn't resolving the same as chrome.

Comment: I cannot find your search pattern in the web page. I can only find a `<h2>Login</h2>` and a `<a onclick="openLogin()">LOGIN</a>`.

Comment: It is in the dialog that gets opened by openLogin(). However, I worked around my issue, I switched to using WebDriver & chromedriver instead of PhpBrowser. I left the question here since I don't really know the answer, only a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your acceptance.suite.yml.

Instead of PhpBrowser use WebDriver.

Comment: While this answer might be correct it would be much more helpful with additional explanation and/or links.